# UIView not receive UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate event

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, uicollectionview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains `UIView` in which have `UICollectionView` inside it. `UIView` have implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`, But when i run `UIView` don't receive event from `UICollectionViewDataSource` and `UICollectionViewDelegate`.

```
- (id)init{
self = [super init];
if(self)
{
    [self initBanDau];
}
return self;
}

- (void)initBanDau{
self.mclv.delegate = self;
self.mclv.dataSource = self;
[self.mclv registerClass:[CellProduct class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
```

I reloadData of `UICollectionView` when `NSMutableArray` change

```
- (void)setMArray:(NSArray *)mArray{
if(_mArray)
{
    [_mArray release];
    _mArray = [mArray retain];
}
else
{
    _mArray = [mArray retain];
}

[self.mclv reloadData];
}
```

Can anyone please explain for me. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Write the below code in different method like `viewDidLoad`:-

```
self.mclv.delegate = self;
self.mclv.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I use custom UIView implement UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionViewDelegate. I put i into awakeFromNib but doesn't work